# What's the software name to indicated key

Tags: audio-recording, tools, desktop-recording, recordmydesktop, video-recording

[image]

anyone knows what's the name of the software that this guy used to indicate the key that he pressed ?

Comment: Why not just ask "this guy"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me the best is [`key-mon`](https://code.google.com/p/key-mon) from [`key-mon` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=key-mon):

[image: key-mon]

You can install it with:

```
sudo apt install key-mon
```

---

For Ubuntu 20.04 LTS it is installable by manual package downloading:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb

wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/k/key-mon/key-mon_1.17-1ubuntu1_all.deb
sudo apt-get install ./key-mon_1.17-1ubuntu1_all.deb
```

Comment: thank you so much, make me easy to shows a shortcut key when i am doing recording

Answer (score 3):

I can't provide you with an answer to what software that guy uses. But I'd suggest you ask him.

Alternatives you might want to look into are: `keymon` https://github.com/scottkirkwood/key-mon

Or: `screenkey` with

```
sudo apt-get install screenkey
```

I hope that helps somehow.