# is there a system-wide, always-on-top tool that shows in the corner of the screen which keyboard keys i'm hitting, no matter which process

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, education

I need such tool to show students which shortcuts I'm using during a demo.

Any ideas? (please)

I intuitively tried Ubuntu's keyboard layout tool, but unfortunately it only works when its window is active. And it is also too large.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the software name to indicated key](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1112518/whats-the-software-name-to-indicated-key)

Comment: @N0rbert It is indeed! Many thanks for the link