# Using Caja file manager on Ubuntu MATE, and every time i rename a file and push the right arrow key, i get moved back to the first file in the folder?

Tags: mate, ubuntu-mate, rename, caja

I'm renaming a lot of files, and anytime I finish typing the name and hit enter and right to go to the next file, I go back to the first file in the folder. Is this a bug?
EDIT: Ubuntu 20.04.1, MATE 1.24.0, and Icon view

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu? Which version of MATE? Which view (List/Icon/Compact)?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.1, MATE 1.24.0, and Icon view

Comment: Can't reproduce. Please record a gif-screencast by [byzanz-record](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/byzanz) with [keymon](https://askubuntu.com/a/1112632/66509) on screen.

Comment: Dont know how to gif-screencast, but it only happens when the window is half screen/only four icons wide. Issue seems to not happen in fullscreen or any other view. Which is also the case for sometimes being unable to rename a file at all until a file is moved out of the folder or the view is widened/changed.